# can't connect a laravel api.php rout from an html form

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to post a form from a HTML file to a live database using laravel api.php route. But it's yielding the following error :

[image]

my api.php looks like :

```
<?PHP

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\User\PageController;


Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
   return $request->user();
});

Route::post('summitRegistration',[PageController::class,'summitRegistration']);
```

My HTML code :

```
 <form action="https://www.aspireelearning.com/summitRegistration" method="POST">
       <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="full_name" id="full_name"
               placeholder="Your Full Name">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone"
               placeholder="Phone Number">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="profession" id="profession"
               placeholder="Profession">
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
           <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email"
              placeholder="Email Address" required>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="organization" id="organization"
              placeholder="Organization/Institute">
              <select class="form-control country-search" name="country" id="country">
                  <option value="">Your Country</option>           
                  <option value="">USA</option>
                  <option value="">UK</option>
                                            
              </select>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
                    CONFIRM
             </button>
        </div>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have update action and also added @csrf token now i hope you will get your out put .

```
   <form action="https://www.aspireelearning.com/api/summitRegistration" method="POST">
    //@csrf
   <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="full_name" id="full_name"
           placeholder="Your Full Name">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone"
           placeholder="Phone Number">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="profession" id="profession"
           placeholder="Profession">
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
       <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email"
          placeholder="Email Address" required>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="organization" id="organization"
          placeholder="Organization/Institute">
          <select class="form-control country-search" name="country" id="country">
              <option value="">Your Country</option>           
              <option value="">USA</option>
              <option value="">UK</option>
                                        
          </select>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">
                CONFIRM
         </button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: I am trying to post it from HTML page, curl URL and @csrf  not gonna work I guess

Comment: @azim you have to try this if any error then add here i will help you .

Comment: it says "Your file couldn’t be accessed"

Comment: remove @csrf then try .

Comment: still same response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236645/discussion-between-rakesh-kumar-oad-and-azim).

Comment: since I am trying to send from a HTML page, HTML page can't recognize laravel curl URL

Comment: now it's saying www.aspireelearning.com refused to connect.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add api as prefix https://www.aspireelearning.com/api/summitRegistration

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: still it says , aspireelearning.com/summitRegistration,  refused to connect

Comment: But it runs in localhost perfectly

Comment: open your laravel.log and make the action then hope you will find out where the error is.
Laravel log path = tail -f  porjrct-path/storage/logs/laravel.log